# Python script error "function object has not attribute 'firstName'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a few scripts of my own to practice what I'm learning. But I'm coming up with some issues on the following script.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
def empInfoEntry():
    firstName = input("Enter Employee's First Name: ")
    lastName = input("Enter Employee's Last Name: ")
    address = input("Enter Employee's Address: ")
    city = input("Enter Employee's City: ")
    state = input("Enter Employee's Complete State: ")
    zip = input("Enter Employee's Zip Code: ")

def empInfo():
    empFirstName = empInfoEntry.firstName
    empLastName = empInfoEntry.lastName
    print (empFirstName + " " + empLastName)
    empAddress = empInfoEntry.address
    print (empAddress)
    empCity = empInfoEntry.city
    empState = empInfoEntry.state
    empZip = empInfoEntry.zip
    print (empCity + ", " + empState + " " + empZip)


empInfoEntry()
empInfo()
```

According to the error "unhandled AttributeError "'function; object has no attribute 'firstName'"

I've looked it up but most of the results I find are quite complex and confusing to grasp my issue here.

I know that when this script runs it starts with `empInfoEntry()`

It works since I can type all the info in.

however, `empInfo()` seems to give me that function error. I have tried also using a simple `print (firstName)` although I know that it's outside of the function. Even when I append it to print `(empInfoEntry.firstName)` it gives me an error.

I can imagine it's because there is no return but i'm still a bit confused about returns as simple as people claim.

Any eli5 responses would be appreciated but a full explanation will work as well.

Thanks.

Also using python 3.4 and eric 6 on windows 8

Comment: You need to use a class, not a function: https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: Why do you expect `empInfoEntry.firstName` to work? `empInfoEntry` is a function that you can call (multiple times) – where would that data be stored?

Comment: Maniac, thank you I need to look more into classes and better understand them.

Poke, I expected `empInfoEntry.firstName` to work because I did not understand that I needed to make it a class and not a function. 

As I stated, I'm attempting to create my own practice scripts rather than following a cookbook and take it for granted.

Thank you both for your responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Firstly, try to use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`.
According to the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input), `input()` is actually `eval(raw_input())`. You might want to know what is `eval()`, check the documentation, we do not discuss it here.</s> Sorry I thought it was Python 2.

As it seems you are not far from start learning Python, I would not write a class for you. Just using functions and basic data structures.

If you are interested, check [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for the naming convention in Python.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def enter_employee_info_and_print():
    # use a dictionary to store the information
    employee_info = {}

    employee_info['first_name'] = input("Enter Employee's First Name: ")
    employee_info['last_name'] = input("Enter Employee's Last Name: ")
    employee_info['address'] = input("Enter Employee's Address: ")
    employee_info['city'] = input("Enter Employee's City: ")
    employee_info['state'] = input("Enter Employee's Complete State: ")
    employee_info['zip'] = input("Enter Employee's Zip Code: ")

    first_name = employee_info['first_name']
    last_name = employee_info['last_name']
    # pay attention that there is no space between `print` and `(`
    print(first_name + " " + last_name)
    address = employee_info['address']
    print(address)
    city = employee_info['city']
    state = employee_info['state']
    zip = employee_info['zip']
    print(city + ", " + state + " " + zip)

# use this statement to run a main function when you are directly running the script.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    enter_employee_info_and_print()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  I think this is the sort of thing your'e looking for.

```
class InfoEntry(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.first_name = input("Enter your first name:")
    self.last_name = input("Enter your last name:")

  def __str__(self):
    return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name

me = InfoEntry()
print(me)
```

Although functions *[can](http://adambeagle.com/blog/python-function-attributes-i/)* have attributes, when you want something to hold information, the format of which you know a priori, the thing you want is a [class](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html)

Comment: Those `first_name` and `last_name` references all need a `self.` in front of them.

Comment: whoops.  This is what happens when you try to write code like it's a text message.  =cD

Comment: I like this method too but I think this is still a bit more advanced than what I'm ready for. Thank you for your answer though. It makes a lot more sense.